# how to post http req with multiple param in angularjs,mongoose

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

In the view html page there is a form with a table and when i submit the form two objects are created cvm and schedules for form and table. i somehow want schedules(which is an array) to be related to cvm form. so i tried this way...

**Here is the defined model**

```
    $scope.addSchedule=function(schedule)
      {
      console.log(schedule.startDate);
      console.log(schedule.location);
      $scope.schedules.push({
        startDate: schedule.startDate,
        location: schedule.location
        });
      schedule.startDate='';
      schedule.location='';
      };
    var inData={'cvm': $scope.cvm,'schedules': $scope.schedules};
    $scope.addCvm=function()
      {
      console.log($scope.cvm);
      console.log($scope.schedules);
      $http.post('/cvmApi',inData).success(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      refresh();
      });
      };
```

**sever side Connection**

 *i guess somthing i missed in this part*

```
/* POST */
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) 
  {
    console.log("Cvm api post '/'");
    console.log("retrieving:: " + req.body);
    cvmModel.create(req.body, function (err, post) {
    console.log("saving:: " + post);
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(post);
      });
  });
```

**Here is my schema for mongodb**

```
               'use strict';

                var mongoose = require('mongoose');

                var cvmSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
                visitOrganization:  { type: String },
                visitAgenda:    { type: String },
                accountManager:     { type: String },
                visitCoordinator:   { type: String },
                schedules:[{
                    startDate: String,
                    location: String
                }]
                });


                module.exports = mongoose.model('visit', cvmSchema);
```

*plz help !! thanks in advance*

Comment: base on your schema `$scope.schedules` should be an array in `$scope.cvm` so your inData should be like this `$scope.cvm.schedules = $scope.schedules; var inData = $scope.cvm`

Comment: any error you are getting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try with below change :

```
//Change addCvm function

$scope.addCvm = function(){
    var inData       = $scope.cvm;
    inData.schedules = $scope.schedules;

    console.log(inData);

    $http.post('/cvmApi',inData).success(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        refresh();
    });
};

// Server Side API Code

router.post('/cvmApi', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("Cvm api post '/'");
    console.log("retrieving:: " + req.body);
    cvmModel.create(req.body, function (err, post) {
    console.log("saving:: " + post);
    if (err) return next(err);
        res.json(post);
    });
});
```

Comment: hey thanku soo much rana i tried bt hit vt an error...! in my chrom console ...->'Object {visitOrganization: "hyd, Telangana, India", visitAgenda: "somthing", accountManager: "sfdxf@dsf.fdx", visitCoordinator: "sfdxf@dsf.fdx", schedules: Array[1]}'
POST  http://localhost:3010/cvmApi  500 (Internal Server Error)

XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost:3010/cvmApi"...._wat to do_

Comment: its giving error because $scope.schedules is not having valid value as per your schema. Try to define $scope.schedules = []; initially in your controller and if possible give me full controller code so that i can get more idea or try to change things for $scope.schedules to set its correct value.

Comment: comeon i dint miss '$scope.schedules = []; '.....i jus wonder if somthing fishy vt schema i defined  ?? bcose i see controller passing data in array manner (in console) bt at server end vt  mongoose r req.body idk???.....

Answer (score 0):

The thing is i dint realize my variable startDate was not in type string in my html page as i was using some date plugins.... 
soo ya thats it worked brilliantly ...

addCvm function in controller *thanks to rana ;-)*

```js
$scope.schedules=[];
$scope.addCvm = function(){
    var inData       = $scope.cvm;
    inData.schedules = $scope.schedules;

    console.log(inData);

    $http.post('/cvmApi',inData).success(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        refresh();
    });
};
```

server side Api

```js
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("Cvm api post '/'");
  console.log("retrieving:: " + req.body);
  cvmModel.create(req.body, function (err, post) {
    console.log("saving:: " + post);
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(post);
  });
});
```

may be not required but i changed my schema though....

```js
var cvmSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
visitOrganization:  { type: String },
visitAgenda:    { type: String },
accountManager:     { type: String },
visitCoordinator:   { type: String },
schedules: [{
    dateStart: { type:String },
    locationHere: { type: String }
}]
});
```